# Converting from 8mm Video Tapes to Digital (PC)

Tags: video

Can you please assist with a recommendation about a good Video Capture Card / Device that can used to convert from 8mm Video Tapes to Digital (PC - Windows)?

I found a site with lots of such devices which are not expensive at all, but since I have ZERO background in this area I am not sure which of them will do the job and will give me the best quality.

Here are 2 examples, I will be more than glad to receive your feedback / suggestions.

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6659984&CatId=1428

http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=612720&CatId=1428

Answer (score 2):

Three years ago I purchased the DIAMOND One Touch Video Capture similar to the 2nd link you provided.:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815306013

This device worked perfectly for converting tons of old VHS tapes to a format suitable for DVDs, I must have converted over 50 tapes this way. I also discovered that I could use this device to capture live broadcasts using the following chain: Antenna --> Video Converter box --> Diamond...Capture --> USB Computer input --> capture software.

The main thing you have to remember is that the conversion is in real time and linear. I had to allow for the tape to play through the parts I wanted to capture at the normal playback speed. On the plus side, the USB interface allows quick and easy set up, no need to open up your computer and install another PCI card.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [Hauppage](http://hauppage.com/) PVR-150 TV-Tuner PCI card (older analog version) that I have used to record from my Hi8 video camera.  I just plug the video from the camera into the card and the sound into my sound card.  The quality of the resulting video seemed to be just as good as the playback from the camera.

Hauppage makes several different products including [USB video capture devices](http://hauppage.com/site/products/data_usblive2.html) similar to the ones you have listed.  The products are good and not too expensive.

There are many other brands and devices, but this is the only brand/device I have personal experience with.